# Cannot get rid of the blue highliht and cannot detect the element it is on

Tags: css, webkit

I have a navigation in a `ul`. The `li` elements are absolutely positioned When I click one of the links in the list, a blue highlight appears. I could not detect the element the highlight is on. Nor could I get rid of it.

I tried:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
user-select: none;

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

I also tried many things on the `ul` and the `li` elements to no avail.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="navigation" class="processed on" style="top: 530px;">
    <div class="navBackground"></div>
    <a class="open on" href="#main-menu">Menü</a>
    <nav id="main-menu" role="navigation" tabindex="-1" class="">
        <ul class="links inline clearfix">
            <li class="menu-529 first"><a href="link1">link1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-562"><a href="link2">link2</a></li>
            <li class="menu-605"><a href="link3">link3</a></li>
            <li class="menu-606"><a href="link4">link4</a></li>
            <li class="menu-563 last"><a href="link5">link5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This is the screenshot of the normal state of the menu:

[image: normal state]

And this is the active state of it. You can see the blue border/highlight:

[image: active state]

To make links obvious, I turned off the background images and gave them a red border:

[image: links with border]

[image: border and highlight]

Still you can see the highlight. There is a 1px gap between the link border and highlight so maybe the highlight is on the `li`, not the link

So I give a black border to the `li`'s but that does not solve it as there is still a gap between the border and the highlight.

[image: li items have border]

And there is always one item that is highlighted (to the left top side of the circle, that is the `.open` link) but it is neither a link (of the menu) nor a `li.

These are screenshots from Chrome browser. In Safari, only that one item is highlighted:

[image: how it looks in Safari]

Now, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use outline:none; in li

Comment: I tried that already. It is not working.

Comment: can you make a fiddle or share css

Comment: i saw the code try using #main-menu:hover, #main-menu:active, #main-menu:focus { outline:none;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this code to your CSS, this should fix the problem:

```
nav#main-menu {
     outline: none;
}
```